# Simplify $\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(-1/x)?$

Tags: trigonometry

As the question says, I want to simplify $\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(-1/x)?$.

There is not necessarily a solution to this, but is there any way to simplify the question above? It can be in terms of anything

Comment: Try drawing some triangles. That is, draw a triangle with angle $\theta$ such that $\tan(\theta)=x$; what can you deduce?

Comment: @JohnLiu A nice similar problem is the one of simplifying $h(x) = \arctan x + \arctan \frac 1x$. That one is actually constant: $h(x)=\frac{\pi}{2} \textrm{sgn}(x)$.

Comment: Expand $\tan(f(x))$ using the $\tan(A+B)$ formula; simplify as much as you can then to get back $f(x)$ take arctan of each side of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have shown that $\left|\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|<\frac{\pi}{2}$, you can use the identity $\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(y)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right)$ to deduce that
\begin{align*}
\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right) &= \tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
&= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{1}{x}}{1+x\cdot\frac{1}{x}}\right)\\
&= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{1}{x}}{2}\right)
\end{align*}